# Suppress warning about conflict with existing identifier

Tags: julia

I'm starting REPL and then using `include("./main.jl")` multiple times to speed up script loading.

After the first run it starts giving warnings:

```
WARNING: replacing module Lib.
WARNING: using Lib.somefn in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier.
```

How to suppress it?

Comment: What do you mean "loading a file many times to speed up script loading?". This doesn't appear to make sense. If it is as understood by the author of the first answer, would you care to edit and clarify?

Comment: @ARamirez julia first start is very slow, so common technic is to start REPL and re-load the file after every change with `include("./main.jl")` instead of re-starting it as a script.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`Revise`](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) and then `includet("./main.jl")` (note the 't' at the end of `includet`, standing for "track"). From there on, whenever you make a change to file "main.jl", these changes are reflected in the REPL, without warning.

Example:

- File main.jl:

```
module Lib

somefn() = 42

end #module
```

- REPL:

```
julia> using Revise
julia> includet("main.jl")
julia> Lib.somefn()
42

# modify the definition of somefn in main.jl and save the file

julia> Lib.somefn()
43
```

---

*NB:* If `Revise` is not already installed on your system, you might have to install it first:

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("Revise")
```

Comment: Is there a way to make Revise to also re-include the changed script automatically?

Comment: You mean: updating function definitions and re-running the parts function calls? If so, then no: Revise does not do this, it only updates the "declarative" parts of your code.